# Is there any way to read the content of gmail request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, gmail

[image: gmail_body_request]

I need to build a web extension. In my extension, I need to listen to every request to gmail to quickly display content to users. But it seems that the content of the email has been simplified, making it difficult to read, and there is no guarantee that this structure will not change in the future. Is there any way I can read the content coming from gmail request

For example, to get the subject of a new incoming mail. I have to use body[2][0][0][4][0][9] with XMLHttpRequest and javascript. This is an unstable and long-term way of retrieving data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.